# Migrating Magento Website Issues

Tags: sql, magento, migration

I am trying to migrate my Magento website but get this screen with a error number, not sure what it means.

[image]

Comment: You might need to look into your log files and find that entry number. Find that and add it to your question.

Comment: Here are the errors that appear in the log:

Comment: I am now able to access the admin, I was missing a / after the url in the database table core_config_data.

Comment: Here is a detailed error message

Comment: you need to navigate var/report and open that error record number, and add it to your question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?